# how to scan java properties file in sonarqube

Tags: properties, sonarqube, rules

I am writing custom rules using SonarQube to scan properties and config files.
Can you please guide me how to write this custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for java properties file https://github.com/racodond/sonar-jproperties-plugin. You can fork it and write your custom rules. 
Here is an example rule wich checks for not allowed key and value combination

```
public class KeyValueCheck extends DoubleDispatchVisitorCheck {
    private static final String SIMPLE_IS_PATTERN_TEMPLATE = "(%s)";
    protected final Pattern patternKey;
    protected final Pattern patternValue;
    private final String VIOLATION_MESSAGE;
    private final boolean matches;
    boolean checkValue = false;

    public KeyValueCheck(String key, String value, String message, boolean matches) {
        VIOLATION_MESSAGE = message;
        this.matches = matches;
        this.patternKey = Pattern.compile(String.format(SIMPLE_IS_PATTERN_TEMPLATE, key), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        this.patternValue = Pattern.compile(String.format(SIMPLE_IS_PATTERN_TEMPLATE, value), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitKey(KeyTree tree) {
        Matcher matcher = patternKey.matcher(tree.text());
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            checkValue = true;
        }

        super.visitKey(tree);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitValue(ValueTree tree) {
        if (checkValue) {
            Matcher matcher = patternValue.matcher(tree.text());
            if (matches == patternValue.matcher(tree.text()).matches()) {
                addPreciseIssue(tree, VIOLATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            checkValue = false;
        }
        super.visitValue(tree);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there some reference material on how to write custom sonarqube rules.

Comment: Is sonarqube multi-lingual, can i get the UI in german or french

Comment: internatinalization https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-l10n-de

Comment: custom sonar rules - There is a lot of examples on the internet, but the best source is the source code of plugins itself. You can get lot of help in SonarQube email groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: Thanks a lot for input